# Emacs - slime - save current functions to file

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp

I'm starting to play with CLisp, and therefore Emacs too, including the "SLIME" plugin (or whatever it's called. How is it called?)

So I've been playing with the REPL for quite some time now, and defined a lot of functions in there with (defun).

Unfortunately, none of these functions have been written in a text file, and I don't fancy retyping all that. Is there a way I could dump or otherwise save the work that has been done in the REPL to a file? (bonus points if the file is Lisp source code :) )

Comment: Have you ever discovered a good way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

SLIME is an elisp program for interacting with Lisp.

There's no simple option to recover functions you've typed only into the repl into a file. [function-lambda-expression](http://l1sp.org/cl/function-lambda-expression) can sometimes return code, but it often does not.

If the repl is still in a buffer, you could copy the whole thing into a file and then use string or regexp replacement to isolate the function definitions.

It's not too hard to avoid this problem in the future.

Most people work by writing definitions into a file, and then using a key combination to send them to Lisp, bypassing the REPL. I use the `C-c C-c` combination when the cursor is on a function to compile and load the expression. `C-x C-e` also works. Then I switch the the REPL to actually use the function.

Answer (score 5):

See also the function `DRIBBLE`, which makes sure a log is written.

```
foo:~$ clisp

...

[1]> (dribble "foo.text")
#<OUTPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"foo.text">
[2]> (+ 3 4)
7
[3]> (defun bar (baz) (* baz baz))
BAR
[4]> (bar 10)
100
[5]> (quit)
Bye.
```

Let's look at the file:

```
foo:~$ more foo.text 
;; Dribble of #<IO TERMINAL-STREAM> started on 2015-05-08 21:38:48.
#<OUTPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"foo.text">
[2]> (+ 3 4)
7
[3]> (defun bar (baz) (* baz baz))
BAR
[4]> (bar 10)
100
[5]> (quit)
Bye.
```

Answer (score 2):

The last paragraph in Xach's answer is what it is all about.

When programming in Lisp, typing function definitions directly into the REPL is the wrong way to do it. The right way is to set up your text editor (emacs) so that with certain keystrokes, the expression at the cursor (the entire function definition) is sent to the REPL. Then to invoke a function, you switch to the REPL. This is what SLIME is for.

Strictly speaking, the text in your emacs buffer doesn't have to be written to a disk file, in which case it will be gone after you close the editor. But normally you save it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can search through your REPL history for the function definitions. If you have the beginning of an expression already typed in, then SLIME will only cycle through previous entries that begin with the same thing:

```
CL-USER> (defun
```

Press `M-P` from there, and you'll cycle through all the `defun`s you've typed in.